# React - unexpected token in state object

Tags: reactjs, eslint, package.json

I am learning in React JS and facing below issue.

I am getting Unexpected token error after npm start. I have simple array in state object. I checked eslintConfig setting exists in package.json then still why this error?

error -

[image]

below is package.json settings -

```
{
  "name": "react-app-1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: tha should be a `:` (colon) instead of a `=` at tags

Comment: I resolved issue by putting : (colon) instead =.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's pretty simple

modify the

this =>

```js
let state = {
tags = ['tag1', 'tag2']
}
```

to =>

```js
let state = {
tags : ['tag1', 'tag2']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `:` inside an object for declaration

```
state = {
    tags: ['tag1','tag2']
}
```